# Why does the Second-Order Axiom schema of Comprehension not lead to Russell's Paradox for ZFC2?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let ZFC2 be the Second-Order formalisation of ZFC.

The Second-Order Axiom schema of Comprehension (part of the deductive system for SOL) says that for every formula (of SOL) there is a relation with the same extension (shapiro 1991).

If we formalise ZFC2, then the domain is all sets and the second-order quantifiers range over all the subsets of the domain. But then, what stops Russell's Paradox from arising?

I know it doesn't because ZFC2 is equivalent to Morse-Kelley set theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [Second-order Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/), the *comprehension schema* (considering for simplicity only unary predicate variables) is:

> **∃X∀x [ ϕ(x) ↔ X(x) ]**,

where **x** is an *individual* variable, **X** is a 1-ary predicate variable and **X** may not occur *free* in **ϕ**.

---

What prevents form generating [Russell's Paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/) ?

Two facts:

*(i)* we cannot substitute **X** for **x**.

A s-o language for sets must use individual variables **x** for *sets* and unary predicate variables for *classes*. So, **x ∈ A** must be formalized as **A(x)** and thus, using it as **ϕ(x)**, what we get is:

> **∃X∀x [ ~A(x) ↔ X(x) ]**.

*(ii)* the proviso that **X** may not be *free* in **ϕ** prevents from using **~X(x)** to get:

> **∃X∀x [ ~X(x) ↔ X(x) ]**.